# Why libvirt bhyve guests does not reboot?

Tags: libvirt

I have libvirt with bhyve driver on FreeBSD 12.
I have FreeBSD guests and Linux guests with UEFI. Both are not able to reboot, just stops when a reboot command issued inside the guest.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the bhyve process just exits if the guest reboots. It takes some external supervisor like runit or s6 to decode the exit status (shutdown, reboot, triple fault, other) and do the right thing.

Comment: libvirtd should be doing this, no?

Comment: Yes, I would expect libvirt to be that external supervisor that decode the exist status and do the right thing

Comment: I use runit or s6 to supervise my bhyve processes and decode the exit code in ./finish scripts.